# iPhone 4.0 problem.. MPMoviePlayerViewController , AVAudio APIs

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making iphone program. The main function is playing video files, and recording sound.

OS 3.1.3 version is fine. But iPhone 4.0 makes problem!!

When I executed playing video (`MPMoviePlayerController`) and continuously recording sound (`AVAudioRecorder`), `AVAudioRecorder` doesn't work....

No recording..!  ;o;

Somebody help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [`useApplicationAudioSession`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW106) property on `MPMoviePlayerController`. In iOS 3.1.x, the movie player was always getting its own system provided audio session. In iOS 4.0, it can now share the application session, and that's the default value as well. Try switching that property to `NO` before starting to play your movie.

Comment: @Franci Penov Your solution solved my video freezing problem but now the sound is stopped when video is playing... Any idea how I could handle this ?