# How to Record the output sound on an iPhone

Tags: xcode

I did a radio player and I want to record sound from him, please help me give ideas ;) Thanks very much. Player is a MPMoviePlayerController.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read this question,  it tells you how to set MPMoviePlayerController to allow to be recorded from an AVAudioRecorder

[iPhone 4.0 problem.. MPMoviePlayerViewController , AVAudio APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233723/iphone-4-0-problem-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-avaudio-apis)

Comment: but that don't help me :( iPhone recorded sound and what you say in microphone, but I need to record only from MPMoviePlayerController :(

Comment: You want to intercept the audio from an MPMoviePlayerController and record that?

Comment: I don't think you can intercept the audio from an MPMoviePLayerController in code.

Comment: :( this is bad :( I think that I will do new player. How do it please give your opinion how I can do this????